# Reading xml node with multiple attributes with bash script

Tags: xml, windows, bash, shell

In xml file with multiple nodes and attributes value. From each node I need to extract "lb" attributes.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<testResults version="1.2">
<httpSample s="sample s1" lb="sample lb1"</httpSample>
<httpSample s="sample s2" lb="sample lb2"</httpSample>
<httpSample s="sample s3" lb="sample lb3"</httpSample>
</testResults>
```

but with my bash script I am not able to do it.
script is:

```
#!/bin/bash
httpSample=($(grep -oP '(?<=httpSample>)[^<]+' "location_of_XML.xml"))

for i in ${!httpSample[*]}
do
  echo "$i" "${httpSample[$i]}"
  # instead of echo use the values to send httpSample, etc
done
$SHELL
```

This script is reading simple xml which has single value of node
like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<testResults version="1.2">
<httpSample>string1</httpSample>
<httpSample>string2</httpSample>
<httpSample>string3</httpSample>
</testResults>
```

Please let me know what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below, even though it's surely not the most efficient way it should give you the values of lb for each xml line containing "httpSample" text :

```
while read line 
do 
  [[ "$line" = *"httpSample"* ]] && { 
    lb=$(echo "$line" | grep 'lb=' | cut -d'=' -f3 | cut -d'<' -f1 | tr -d '"')
   # now do here whatever you want with "$lb" variable 
  }
done < xml_file
```

Comment: with minor update I am getting all attributes value but how to filter only "lb" value.             httpSample=($(grep -oP '(?<=httpSample)[^<]+' "sample.xml"))

for i in ${!httpSample[*]}
do
  echo "$i" "${httpSample[$i]}"
  # instead of echo use the values to send httpSample, etc
done
$SHELL

Comment: @ashmalvi see updated answer. The lb value is assigned to $lb variable. You can do whatever you want with it.